# Question about generics in C# comparing to Java

Tags: c#, java, .net, generics, covariance

In Java I can specify generic with wildcard "?". It is possible to create a map like this one:

`Map<String, ?>`.

I'm working with C# and I need a `Dictionary<String, SomeInterface<?>>` (where ? can be int, double, any type). Is this possible in C#?

**EDIT:**

Example:

```
interface ISomeInterface<out T>{
 T Method();
 void methodII();
}

class ObjectI : ISomeInterface<int>{
    ...
}
class ObjectII : ISomeInterface<double>{
    ...
}
class ObjectIII : ISomeInterface<string>{
    ....
}
```

I was trying to map this objects into Dictionary like:

```
Dictionary<String, ISomeInterface<?>> _objs = new Dictionary<String, ISomeInterface<?>();

_objs.Add("Object1", new ObjectI());
_objs.Add("Object2", new ObjectII());
_objs.Add("Object3", new ObjectII());

foreach(var keyVal in _objs){
   Console.WriteLine(keyVal.Method());
}
```

Objects that implement  ISomeInterface are loaded in runtime using Assembly and Activator.createInstance. In the moment of creation I don't if objects implements  `ISomeInterface<int>` or `ISomeInterface<double>`.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know Java that much but wouldn't `?` be the same as `Object` then?

Comment: Yes, `?` is `Object`. What's more unexpected is that *anything* you write there is actually `Object`, because Java's VM doesn't actually support generics, so they all get erased at compile time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

However, if you're using C# 4, you can make `ISomeInterface` [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) so that `ISomeInterface<Anything>` will be convertible to `ISomeInterface<object>`.

If `ISomeInterface` has methods that take parameters of its type parameter (as opposed to return values), this will be completely impossible, since it would then allow you to pass arbitrary objects as the parameters.

**EDIT**: In your specific case, the best solution is to make `IMyInterface<T>` inherit a separate non-generic `IMyInterface` interface and move all members that don't involve `T` to the base interface.
You can then use a `Dictionary<string, IMyInterface>` and you won't have any trouble.

Answer (score 2):

There is the possibility to restrict your type variables to certain types:

```
public class Map<U, T> where T : IInterface
{
}
```

However, you can't do something like:

```
Map<string, T> map = new Map<string, T>()
```

Answer (score 2):

For the usage you're describing, you could use a workaround, with an `IDictionary<string, ISomeInterface>`:

```
interface ISomeInterface
{
    object Method();
    void Method2();
}

interface ISomeInterface<T> : ISomeInterface
{
    T Method();
}

class C1 : ISomeInterface<int>
{
    object ISomeInterface.Method() { return Method(); }
    public int Method() { return 10; }
    public void Method2() { }
}
```